# PHP looped data will not echo outside the while function OR how can I pass looped data by echoing out of the while function?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, echo

I have a loop of data that will only echo the loop inside the while function, but if i call/echo the looped data outside the while function, it only runs the 1st loop.

SAMPLE:

```
$num = mysql_num_rows($queryFromDB);
$i=0;
while($i < $num)
{
    $field1= mysql_result($queryFromDB,$i,"field1");
    $field2= mysql_result($queryFromDB,$i,"field2");

    $bothFields = $field1 . " " . $field2 "\n";

    // This will show 2 rows of data
    echo $bothFields;

    $i++;

    // This will only show 1 row of data. How can I pass the looped data to another variable?
    echo $bothFields;

}
```

The output that I wanted to show is:

TITLE/HEADER GOES HERE in the 1st Line

-1st Row of Data from DB

-2nd Row of Data from DB

Here's the actual code:
$num = mysql_num_rows($qWoundAssessment);

$i=0;
while ($i < $num)
{
$wndType = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndType");
$wndNum = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndNum");
$wndLocation = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndLocation");
$wndStage = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndStage");
$wndL = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndL");
$wndD = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndD");
$wndW = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndW");
$wndAseptic = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndAseptic");
$wndIrrigate = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndIrrigate");
$wndIrrigateBox = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndIrrigateBox");
$wndPat = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndPat");
$wndCover = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndCover");
$wndCoverBox = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndCoverBox");
$wndSecure = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndSecure");
$wndSecureBox = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndSecureBox");
$wndQvisit = mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndQvisit");

$wnd = "-" . $wndType . " " . "#" . $wndNum . ", " . "LOCATION " . $wndLocation . ", " . "STAGE " . $wndStage;
$wndSize = "SIZE " . $wndL . "CM" . " X " . $wndW . "CM" . " X " . $wndD;
if($wndAseptic=="1"){$wndAsepticTech = "USING ASEPTIC TECHNIQUE";}
if($wndIrrigate=="1"){$wndIrrigateWith = "IRRIGATE WITH " . $wndIrrigateBox;}
if($wndPat=="1"){$wndPatDry = "PAT DRY";}
if($wndCover=="1"){$wndCoverWith = "COVER WITH " . $wndCoverBox;}
if($wndSecure=="1"){$wndSecureWith = "COVER WITH " . $wndSecureBox;}
if($wndQvisit=="1"){$wndQv = "Q VISIT";}

if(isset($wnd, $wndSize, $wndAsepticTech, $wndIrrigateWith, $wndPatDry, $wndCoverWith, $wndSecureWith, $wndQv)){
$woundCare = implode(", ",array($wnd, $wndSize, $wndAsepticTech, $wndIrrigateWith, $wndPatDry, $wndCoverWith, $wndSecureWith, $wndQv)) . "\n\n ";}

$wndCare .= $woundCare;

$i++;
}

$snWoundCare = "SN TO PROVIDE SKILLED NURSING VISITS FOR WOUND CARE:" . "\n" . $wndCare;

if I echo $wndCare, it shows the "Undefined variable" error with the actual looped data. But if I pass this variable to PDF, it works.

SN TO PROVIDE SKILLED NURSING VISITS FOR WOUND CARE:

-PRESSURE ULCER #1, LOCATION COCCYX, 3, SIZE 2.0CM X 1.5CM X 0.07, USING ASEPTIC TECHNIQUE, IRRIGATE WITH NORMAL SALINE, PAT DRY, COVER WITH AQUACEL AG, COVER WITH MEPILEX BORDER, Q VISIT

-SURGICAL WOUND #2, LOCATION (R) KNEE, , SIZE 29CM X 0CM X 0, USING ASEPTIC TECHNIQUE, IRRIGATE WITH NORMAL SALINE, PAT DRY, COVER WITH AQUACEL AG, COVER WITH MEPILEX BORDER, Q VISIT

================ CODE NOW WORKS!!! HERE's MY FINAL SOLUTION ======================
$num = mysql_num_rows($qWoundAssessment);
$i=0;
$storeMyData = array();
while($i < $num)
    {
    $wnd= "-" . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndType") . " #" . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndNum"). ", LOCATION " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndLocation") . ", STAGE " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndStage");
    $wndSize = "SIZE " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndL") . "CM" . " X " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndW") . "CM" . " X " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndD") . "CM";
    if(isset($rowWoundAssessment['wndAseptic'])){$wndAsepticTech = "USING ASEPTIC TECHNIQUE";}
    if(isset($rowWoundAssessment['wndIrrigate'])){$wndIrrigateWith = "IRRIGATE WITH " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndIrrigateBox");}
    if(isset($rowWoundAssessment['wndPat'])){$wndPatDry = "PAT DRY";}
    if(isset($rowWoundAssessment['wndCover'])){$wndCoverWith = "COVER WITH " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndCoverBox");}
    if(isset($rowWoundAssessment['wndSecure'])){$wndSecureWith = "SECURE WITH " . mysql_result($qWoundAssessment,$i,"wndSecureBox");}
    if(isset($rowWoundAssessment['wndQvisit'])){$wndQvisit = "Q VISIT";}

```
$wndCare = implode (", ", array($wnd, $wndSize, $wndAsepticTech, $wndIrrigateWith, $wndPatDry, $wndCoverWith, $wndSecureWith, $wndQvisit)). "\n\n";

    // This will show 2 rows of data

    $storeMyData[] = $wndCare ;  // store current data in array
    $i++;
}
```

/* this will echo your storedData of loop */
foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)

/* or join the data using string concatenation */
$allFinalData2 = "";
/* this will echo your storedData of loop */
foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)
    {
        $allFinalData2 = $allFinalData2.$prevData ;  // keep on concatenating
    }
echo "SN TO PROVIDE SKILLED NURSING VISITS FOR WOUND CARE:" . "\n" . $allFinalData2;

thanks to DhruvPathak and Antonio Laguna! You guys are the best! Just made my day! *jumps around the room*

Comment: 1. while is not a function; 2. the second echo $bothFields; is not inside while{};

Comment: what is your goal here.. it think your approach might be totally wrong but im not sure what you are trying to do...

Comment: Liangliang - sorry newbie here :) I wanted to pass the looped data to another variable so I can link this to PDF field via FPDP.

Comment: prodigitalson - I just updated my question with my goal. Like what I told Liangliang, I need to pass the looped data to a variable so I can link this variable to a PDF field via FPDF, so no HTML.. just pure data with "\n" breaks in some areas. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to do with your data. It seems you want to store
all the data to use it outside the loop, then this is the way to go :

```
<?php
$num = mysql_num_rows($queryFromDB);
$i=0;
$storeMyData = array();
while($i < $num)
{
    $field1= mysql_result($queryFromDB,$i,"field1");
    $field2= mysql_result($queryFromDB,$i,"field2");

    $bothFields = $field1 . " " . $field2 "\n";

    // This will show 2 rows of data
    echo $bothFields;
    $storeMyData[] = $bothFields ;  // store current data in array
    $i++;


}


/* this will echo your storedData of loop */
foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)
  {
     echo $prevData."\n";
  }

?>

 $allFinalData = implode("",$prevData);  // implode will join all the data as string
 echo $allFinalData."\n" ; 

/* or join the data using string concatenation */
 $allFinalData2 = "";
   /* this will echo your storedData of loop */
foreach($storeMyData as $prevData)
  {
    $allFinalData2 = $allFinalData2.$prevData ;  // keep on concatenating
  }

 echo $allFinalData2,"\n";

?>
```

Comment: hi DhruvPathak! thanks for the answer. However this is similar to my problem with while, but instead with foreach. I need to pass all the looped data into a variable and not echo the looped data. Is there a way I can output $prevData into another variable with all the looped strings?

Comment: yes , you surely can. I have modified the code if i can understand your requirement correctly.

Comment: hi DhruvPathak! sorry i got back to this so late. the page i was working got overwrite by accident and had to rebuild it again. anyways, i got the time to test your code, unfortunately it generates an error "Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed" related to this line " $allFinalData = implode("",$prevData);  // implode will join all the data as string"

Comment: i played with this code a bit and got it all figured out with no issues!!! thank you djruvpathak! I will be adding the correct code above. thanks to antonio laguna as well! you guys are the best!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<?php
$wndCare = '';

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qWoundAssessment)){
    $wnd = '-'.$row['wndType'].' #'..$row['wndNum'].', LOCATION '.$row['wndLocation'].', STAGE '.$row['wndStage'];
    $wndSize = 'SIZE '.$row['wndL'].'CM X '.$row['wndW'].'CM X '.$row['wndD'];

    $wndAsepticTech = ($row['wndAseptic'] == 1) ? 'USING ASEPTIC TECHNIQUE' : '';
    $wndIrrigateWith = ($row['wndIrrigate'] == 1) ? 'IRRIGATE WITH '.$row['wndIrrigateBox'] : '';
    $wndPatDry = ($row['wndPat'] == 1) ? 'PAT DRY' : '';
    $wndCoverWith = ($row['wndCover'] == 1) ? 'COVER WITH'.$row['wndCoverBox'] : '';
    $wndSecureWith = ($row['wndSecure'] == 1) ? 'COVER WITH'.$row['wndSecureBox'] : '';
    $wndSecureWith = ($row['wndSecure'] == 1) ? 'COVER WITH'.$row['wndSecureBox'] : '';
    $wndQvisit = ($row['wndQvisit'] == 1) ? 'Q VISIT' : '';

    $wndCare .= implode (", ", array($wnd, $wndSize, $wndAsepticTech, $wndIrrigateWith, $wndPatDry, $wndCoverWith, $wndSecureWith, $wndQv)). '\n\n';
}
$snWoundCare = "SN TO PROVIDE SKILLED NURSING VISITS FOR WOUND CARE:" . "\n" . $wndCare;
?>
```

The issue I see is that you were testing if all variables where previously setted and this could make strange things as you were stablishing them sometimes and sometimes don't.

Comment: I tried to echo $output[0] and $output[1] outside the while, and I get the first character from the 2nd row data (DB) for $output[0] and the 2nd character from the 2nd row data (DB) for output[1]. For my case, I might have like 10 rows of data in MySQL. And I need to store these number of rows of data (could be 5, 10, 100) into a single variable that will pass into PDF field via FPDP.

Comment: This have no sense for me... What kind of data do you output when you echo $field1 for example? If it is a string it should be correctly saved to the array. As for the length problem, if it works as I expect, you should be able to know the number of elements doing count($output);

Comment: while for answers, i came across a similar problem. http://www.phpfreaks.com/forums/index.php?topic=292423.0 I tried to do the same logic with mine, but it didn't work. I'm able to output the data that I wanted in order but I have to echo it inside the while loop. I don't need it to echo it, I just need to store all looped data into a single variable, then use that to pass to PDF. However if I have that variable outside the loop, it only display the last row of data and not all.

Comment: I think I understanded what you mean. Updating the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update! For some reason, the $values echoed all rows of data, but on top of those data, there was an error "Notice: Undefined variable: $values"

Comment: Please, paste all the code you have. Update your answer because I don't know what's the matter here without viewing the code.

Comment: it's gonna be alooooong code. I tried to pass the data to PDF and it worked with no issues. I have another php test page to echo the data and that's where it shows the undefined variable.

Comment: i made an update to my post with all the actual code i'm dealing with :)

Comment: hey antonio! sorry i got back to this code so late. I accidentally overwrite my php page by accident with 500+ lines of code and I had to rebuild them from ground zero. Anyways, the updated code didn't work. it only displays the 1st row of data and not 2. In case there's no other solution to his, would you mind bringin back to previous code that used to work (exporting data to PDF) even if it generates php error in php page by echoing it?